# How do I call a method from a class that was not instantiated in Java?

Tags: java, class

I would like to start off by apologizing for the bad title. I know the title can be improved, but I do not know the term that is appropriate. Help with the title is appreciated.

As for my question, I am curious if I can call a method from the 'Friend' class. I'm not sure how to explain my question, so I hope this code helps.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

  int friends = 0;

  while(friends < 3) {
    new Friend().talk("Hello");
    friends ++;

    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  // How do I call the 'goodbye()' method from one of the 'Friend' classes?

  }
}
```

Friend Class:

```
public class Friend {

  int talk = 0;

  public Friend() {
  }

  public void talk(final String word) {

    Thread speech = new Thread() {
      public void run() {

        while(talk < 5) {
          System.out.println(talk + ": " + word);

          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
               ie.printStackTrace();
           }

          talk ++;
        }

      }
    };

    speech.start();

  }

    public void goodbye() {
      talk = 5;
    }

}
```

Please let me know if I can call the methods from classes if I create the class objects like I showed above. Also, if someone could please tell me the proper term for calling methods from classes like I showed, it would be a huge help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the problem with `new Friend().goodbye()`?

Comment: Are you looking for static methods? `public static void talk` ... so you can call the talk method without having to instantiate a new object every time... `Friend.talk`

Comment: You can call any public non-static method of `Friend` once you have an object of that type. You may wish to keep that instance in a variable and call both `talk` and `goodbye` from it. If you want "class-based methods" that don't require an object, you want static methods.

Comment: +Luigi Cortese Wouldn't that create a new instant of the Friend class? I would like to call the 'goodbye()' method with one of the existing instances of the 'Friend' class created in the while loop if possible.

Comment: Instead of doing `new Friend().talk("Hello");`, you could do `Friend afriend = new Friend(); afriend.talk("Hello");` and the later on call `afriend.goodbye();`, no?

Comment: @Rane1011 sure it would, read my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If static isn't what you're looking for which I tend to believe because of your comment and where it exists in the code

> How do I call the 'goodbye()' method from one of the 'Friend' classes?

then your question is misleading in the sense that you really are instantiating objects. In this example I create Friends and store them in an array.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int count = 0;

    //you can store reference to Friend in an array
    Friend[] friends = new Friend[3];

    //in the loop, you make 3 new Friends
    while (count < 3) {
        friends[count] = new Friend();
        count++;
    }

    //Since they're instantiated and stored in the array, you can call their methods later
    friends[0].goodbye();
    //or
    friends[1].goodbye();
    //or
    friends[2].goodbye();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's better :P. Btw you could also write `friends[count++] = new Friend();` if you like keep that in one line (just an info :)).

Comment: Sorry I had a hard time explaining that this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your `main` method create an instance of the `Friend` class

```
Friend f=new Friend();
```

then call its methods

```
f.talk("Hello");
f.goodbye();
...
```

Doing so you will be referring to the same object. In your case, this is what you get

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int friends = 0;
    Friend f = new Friend();
    while (friends < 3) {
        f.talk("Hello");
        friends++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    f.goodbye();
}
```

Comment: How do I create multiple instances of the 'Friend' class in a while loop with this method?

Comment: what do you mean...? `new Friend();` creates an instance, `Friend f2=new Friend();` will create another instance referenced by `f2`

Comment: @Rane1011 I edited my answer, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about `static` fields and methods? They can be called without instantiation. Define a class like

```
public class Friend {
    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then, in your main method, you can call it simply as

```
Friend.sayHello();
```

This is an example of calling a method on a class that is not instantiated in Java. Further reading - [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to create objects in Java

1. **Using new keyword**

This is the most common way to create an object in Java.

```
Friend f = new Friend();
f.talk("Hello");
```

2. **Using Class.forName()**

Friend class has a **public default constructor** so you can create an object in this way.

```
Friend f = (Friend) Class.forName("Friend").newInstance();
```

3. **Using clone()**

The clone() can be used to create a copy of an existing object.

```
Friend anotherF = new Friend(); 
Friend f= anotherF.clone();
```

4. **Using object deserialization**

Object deserialization is nothing but creating an object from its serialized form.

```
ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(anInputStream ); 
Friend f= (Friend) inStream.readObject();
```

You can use any one of them to create object and then call the method.

Comment: `Friend f= Friend.clone();` this doesn't look right.

Comment: opps typo.Corrected.Thanks Tom